# IllegalStateException when ListView item count changes while scrolling

Tags: android, listview, illegalstateexception

I know there are dozens of posts about IllegalStateExceptions in ListViews, but no solution worked for me. Hopefully someone can help me find out what I am doing wrong.

**What's going on?**

When a certain property in my SharedPreferences is updated, I update the ArrayList which provides the data for the ListView, and notify the ListView. An IllegalStateException is thrown **only on Android 4** (never on Android 2.3), when the **number of items in the ListView changes** and the **user is scrolling** when the update happens.

**IllegalStateException**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131165193, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.example.view.StatusActivity$StatusAdapter)]
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1545)
at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4082)
[...]
```

**The Code**

Here's a minimal version of the Activity concerned. The ListView update is triggered from onSharedPreferenceChanged, where I also made sure that the update is executed on the UI thread (as opposed to what the IllegalStateException suggests).

```
public class StatusActivity extends Activity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private ArrayList<Status> stati;
    private ListView listview;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private StatusAdapter adapter;

    private static final int TYPE_STATUS = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_status);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new StatusAdapter();
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        updateList();
    }

    public void updateList(){
        StatusDAO.initialize(this);
        stati = (ArrayList<Status>) StatusDAO.readAll();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listview.invalidateViews();
        listview.refreshDrawableState();
    }

    private class StatusAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Status current;

        public int getCount() {
                return stati.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
                return stati.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
        }

        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                return TYPE_STATUS;
        }

        public int getViewTypeCount() {
                return 1;
        }

        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            return false;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if(convertView == null) {
                    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(StatusActivity.this);
                    final int layout = R.layout.item_status;
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            } 


            // [..]

            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if(key.equals(Configuration.PREF_LOADINGSTATUS)){   
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    updateList();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

I have no idea how to fix this issue, since I have already tried everything that is suggested on the internet (making sure the update to the dataset happens on the UI thread; calling notifyDataSetChanged(); ...).

I would be very grateful for your help and suggestions, any help is appreciated!